# Clicking a button with Javascript on an official website (chrome extension)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, button

I'm trying to create a chrome extension that clicks a button on a website using the DOM.click() method. (https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_html_click.asp)

EDIT: The purpose of this chrome extension is to create a keyboard shortcut to toggle on/off English Subtitles while watching a foreign language video. Having to use your mouse and dragging it to open a menu to turn on subtitles when you need them can be inconvenient if you are trying to understand the language without the subtitles. I wanted to create a keyboard shortcut that would immediately turn on the subtitles. An example of such a website is 
(https://www.ondemandkorea.com/ask-us-anything-e102.html)

```
<button type="button" class="jw-reset jw-settings-content-item" role="menuitemradio" aria-checked="false">English</button>
```

This is button on the website I'm trying to click with Javascript

In my code, I have a window listener that waits for the specific website to load. Then, to find the button I want to click, I call *document.getElementsByClassName("Class Name")* and look through the returned elements array for a button that that says *English* and save it into *var englishButton*. I add another listener that listens for a keyboard key to be pressed which in turn presses *englishButton*.

However, when I click the shortcutKey, *englishButton.click();* doesn't seem to do anything. I know that the correct English Button is found and that my shortcutKey Listener works through the use of *console.log()* statements.

I can't seem to understand why the button won't click.

EDIT: After adding a buttonListener to the code, the English button does click after all, but it does not turn on the subtitles for the video

Here's my code.

```
  /*
Looking for the subtitle button that states "English"
*/
var englishButton;
window.addEventListener("load", function(event) {

    var buttonList = document.getElementsByClassName('jw-reset jw-settings-content-item');

    for (var i = 0, len = buttonList.length; i < len; i++){
        if(buttonList[i].textContent === "English") {
          englishButton = buttonList[i];
          break;
        }

    }
    englishButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
      console.log('englishButton clicked!');
    });

    /*
    Event Listener that detects when the shortcut key is hit.
    When the shortcut Key is hit. It will simulate a mouse click on the subtitle button
    */

    document.addEventListener('keyup', function(e){
        if(e.key === shortcutKey){
          console.log('shortcut pressed')
          englishButton.click();
        }
      }
    );

});
```

Comment: Have you tried moving your `keyup` listener inside of your `load` listener?

Comment: What @ryanpcmcquen said is worth trying. This may very well be due to asynchronous execution of the functions. I suspect `document.addEventListener`  executes before `window.addEventListner`. In that case, `englishButton` doesn't have the dom element when you're clicking it.

Comment: @ba_ul. That seems like it would do the trick, but after tinkering around with it, it still doesn't seem to work

Comment: @DanielChoi, would you mind providing HTML as well so that we could help reproduce the problem?

Comment: I got it to work with the structure as it is. How do you know the button click is not happening? I don't see any event listener for the button in your code.

Comment: See my code here. https://codepen.io/asifm_/pen/YROOqB?editors=1011

Comment: @ryanpcmcquen I added the website I was trying to run this code on and some background context of what my ultimate goal is

Comment: @ba_ul I implemented a button event listener to see if it was being clicked. And it is being clicked after all. Thank you for that. However, even though the button is clicked, it doesn't show the subtitles on that video for some reason (I added more information about my ultimate goal at the top). I know I'm asking a lot and that you already technically answered my question, but I think was looking at the problem from the wrong angle

Comment: @DanielChoi, I would probably ask that as a new question.

Answer (score 1):

In your comments under your question, you confirmed that the button is actually triggering the click. So the issue for you is rather producing the intended result from the click. Which is to toggle on and off the English caption. There's a better, simpler, and much more reliable alternative here.

The website uses JW Player to show its video. They have a well-documented and open API (https://developer.jwplayer.com/jw-player/docs/developer-guide).

All you have to do is something like this

```
jwplayer().setCurrentCaptions(X)
```

Here X is the index number of the caption option you want to select from within the list of all captions that are available in a particular video.

In your example video, the list has only two items:

0: Off
1: English

So to turn on English:

```
jwplayer().setCurrentCaptions(1)
```

And to turn off all caption:

```
jwplayer().setCurrentCaptions(0)
```

If the index would vary from one video to another, you need to first get the list of captions available and then find the index number for English.

```
let allCaptions = jwplayer().getCaptionsList();
englishCaptionIndex = allCaptions.findIndex(caption => caption.label == 'English');
```

That's it.

You can do all kinds of interesting things using the API.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use jQuery, so you can use functions like keyup() or keydown() so you can listen when a key is pressed. Also a better practice is to check the element by id if we only want to watch over a DOM element instead of using a class.

Comment: Thanks! I'll definitely look into jQuery more. As for the second part, I would use getElementById but the button on the website doesn't have an id at all so I have to use find by class and loop through the array

Comment: $(".class:contains('English')").click(); in jQuery

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Move all your code into your `load` listener:

https://codepen.io/ryanpcmcquen/pen/EOerPM?editors=1011

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function(event) {
   /*
   Looking for the subtitle button that states "English"
   */
   var englishButton;
   // console.log('Website loaded. englishButton:', englishButton);
   var buttonList = document.getElementsByClassName("jw-reset");

   for (var i = 0, len = buttonList.length; i < len; i++) {
      if (buttonList[i].textContent === "English") {
         englishButton = buttonList[i];
         // console.log("englishButton found", englishButton);
         break;
      }
   }
   // console.log("End of window-load's callback. englishButton:", englishButton);
   /*
   Event Listener that detects when the shortcut key is hit.
   When the shortcut Key is hit. It will simulate a mouse click on the subtitle button
   */
   document.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
      console.log(
         "Inside document-keyup's callback. englishButton:",
         englishButton
      );
      if (e.key == "z") {
         //Logic to press the subitle button
         console.log(
            "Key matched: ",
            e.key,
            "Now click button. englishButton:",
            englishButton
         );
         englishButton.click();
         console.log("Shortcut Key");
      } else {
         console.log("Random Key");
      }
   });

   englishButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
      console.log("englishButton clicked!");
   });
});
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8" />
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
   <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
   <button type="button" class="jw-reset">English</button>
</body>

</html>
```

But there are some things that could be improved in your code, so let's take a look at a more 'modernized' version of your code (comments in code):

```js
// Using the `window` `load` event is fine, but
// you should prefer the `document` `DOMContentLoaded`
// event when possible, since it fires when the DOM
// has been constructed, while `load` means all assets have fully loaded (images).
// For your case since you are relying only on elements,
// `DOMContentLoaded` is a better choice.
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
   /*
   Looking for the subtitle button that states "English"
   */
   var englishButton;

   // Use `querySelectorAll` since it is more dynamic and
   // will accept any type of selector. Also, for loops
   // are avoided in most modern JavaScript because
   // they create scoping and off-by-one errors.
   // Since you want to break out of the loop here,
   // we will use `.some()`. `Array.prototype.slice.call()`
   // converts the NodeList returned by `querySelectorAll`
   // into an Array.
   Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".jw-reset")).some(
       function (button) {
           if (button.textContent === 'English') {
               englishButton = button;
               return true;
           }
       }
   );
   
   /*
   Event Listener that detects when the shortcut key is hit.
   When the shortcut Key is hit. It will simulate a mouse click on the subtitle button
   */
   document.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
      console.log(
         "Inside document-keyup's callback. englishButton:",
         englishButton
      );
      if (e.key === "z") {
         //Logic to press the subitle button
         console.log(
            "Key matched: ",
            e.key,
            "Now click button. englishButton:",
            englishButton
         );
         englishButton.click();
         console.log("Shortcut Key");
      } else {
         console.log("Random Key");
      }
   });

   englishButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
      console.log("englishButton clicked!");
   });
});
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8" />
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
   <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
   <button type="button" class="jw-reset">English</button>
</body>

</html>
```